# Deleting gcs redundant gcs buckets

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gcloud, gsutil

I am trying to clean up my GCS storage which has redundant bucket of more than 3 years created on a daily basis. for few of them are no longer needed. I am trying to do like

`gsutil -l  | grep 'gs://bucket-name-.*' | gsutil rb -f`

is this a right way?

Comment: resolved it by ```gsutil -l | grep 'gs://bucket-name-.*' | xargs -I{} gsutil -m rm -r -f {}```

Comment: Do you want to remove the buckets (the ones more than 3 years) or the content of the buckets (files more than 3 years)?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere just a plain clean up of all the buckets which are matching the pattern. that's it. For time base removal I have Lifecycle policy.

Answer (score 2):

The [`gsutil rb` command](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/rb) is used to delete buckets although a requirement is that the buckets are empty in order to be succesfully deleted.

To delete your buckets and all its contents, use the [`gsutil rm` command](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/rm#description) with the `-r` option. Running gsutil rm -r on a bucket will delete all versions of all objects in the bucket, and then delete the bucket:

```
gsutil rm -r gs://bucket
```

Also note that to delete a large number of objects in your buckets, using gsutil takes a long time to complete. Using Cloud Console instead is recomended.
You may find more details in the [Deleting Best Practices](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/best-practices#deleting) documentation.

Hope you find this helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your buckets are empty the [rb](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/rb#synopsis) flag will work to delete the buckets and you'd need to use the [ls](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/listing-buckets#gsutil) flag to list the buckets associated with your project (I assume that the -l flag was a typo).

Notice that if your bucket still has objects you'd need to recur to the [gsutil rm -r gs://BUCKET_NAME](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/deleting-buckets) as the buckets being empty is a requirement for using the `rb` flag.

Your script is missing a way to pipe the bucket name to the `gsutil rb -f` command. E.g. imagine you have a bucket named `gs://my-cool-bucket`, the following commands will mirror what you are trying to achieve (taking into consideration that the `my-cool-bucket` is not empty):

```
gsutil ls | grep 'gs://my-cool-bucket' | xargs gsutil rm -r
```

The following [post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/108782/pass-the-output-of-previous-command-to-next-as-an-argument) within the community will be useful is you are interested in exploring any other possible ways of passing the output of a previous command as an argument to the next command when piping commands using bash.

Be very careful when using automation to delete buckets and objects within buckets, as neither the objects, nor the buckets can be recovered after deletion. If you want to delete buckets that have a large number of objects it is recommended to use the Cloud Console instead of using `gsutil` or any source of automation.